# Exception in rewrite rule within .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a ReWrite rule as follows :

```
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ "http://example2.com/test?id=$1" [NE,L,QSA]
```

Which basically redirects anything that follows my domain name (e.g. **www.example1.com/testing** to **www.example2.com/test?id=testing**). I have both example1 and example2 pointing to the same IP.

I want to add an exception within the above rule such that **www.example1.com/abcxyz** is not considered by the rule at all.

I tried `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/abcxyz` but it seems to error out by saying too many redirections. Am I missing out on something here??

Comment: didn't get your question can you please explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is being caused by your redirect URL matching the redirect again. You need to exclude that too. Try:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/abcxyz
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/test
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ http://example2.com/test?id=$1 [NE,L,QSA]
```

Remember that the query string is not part of the match for a `RewriteRule` so redirecting to `test` is matching itself again and causing the loop.

You don't need to escape dots in character classes, so I changed that. The double quotes aren't needed.

Are you redirecting or rewriting? If redirecting you should be explicit and add the `R` flag with the desired type. For a `301` use:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/abcxyz
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/test
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ http://example2.com/test?id=$1 [R=301,NE,L,QSA]
```

If rewriting you shouldn't have the domain and protocol in there:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/abcxyz
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/test
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ /test?id=$1 [NE,L,QSA]
```

Comment: My mistake was that I was writing the Rewrite rule before the RewriteCond, didn't realize that mattered. The RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/abcxyz seemed to work ok after that.

Comment: Great, glad you got it fixed. The RewriteCond directives do actually run after the RewriteRule has matched, but yes they must be placed before. I guess your actual rewritten URLs don't match themselves then, only your example does that.